# Designing Android layouts

Tags: android

I need to develop an app to submit job details to server.My layout will have something like this below:

Emp name : Edit text for entering the name ID: Edit text 
work number: Edit text 
attach pic: Edit text browse button
            Edit text  browse (max 4 pictures)

Once the picture is attached, I want it to appear next to attach pic as an icon and a delete button should appear.  Is it possible for the pic to appear as an icon?
Let me know which layout should I chose to achieve this linear or relative ? Which one is easier
It needs to be supported on mobile & tablet.

Comment: Why do you need to develop the app? Tell them you have no idea how to program with Android so they give you time to learn the basics.

Comment: Outsource to someone else.. :p

Answer (score 1):

If layout-hierarchy is NOT complex then `LinearLayout` is faster than `RelativeLayout`. If you think your requirement may get complex later(seems like yours will) then it is advisable that you use `RelativeLayout`.